# There is a voice delay while using linphone-sdk

Tags: sip, rtp, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am doing various tests to make an application with linphone's android library. I I have a problem during testing (I am using EasyLinphone Demo).

When I make a call from Android to PC, the sound coming from my PC to Android sounds very delayed or does not sound for a few seconds. Through the example of Easylinphone between Android and Android (https://github.com/forever4313/EasyLinphone) this problem did not occur. However, there is a problem when Android calls the PC first. This delay is very serious for my work.

Looked into this problem and found the following logcat.
I would like to ask you for a suggestion on how to solve this problem.

```
 logcat Message
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
07-05 04:53:51.800 4285-5556/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone E/huanyutong: rtp_parse: discarding too old packet (seq_num=13638, ts=22080)

07-05 04:53:51.820 4285-5556/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone E/huanyutong: rtp_parse: discarding too old packet (seq_num=13639, ts=22240)

07-05 04:53:51.940 4285-5556/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone I/huanyutong: Stun packet sent on rtcp for session [0x74e36ba0]

07-05 04:53:52.260 4285-4285/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone I/huanyutong: Bandwidth usage for call [0x74c5b620]:
                                                                            RTP  audio=[d= 80.0,u= 80.0], video=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0], text=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0] kbits/sec
                                                                            RTCP audio=[d=  0.0,u=  0.8], video=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0], text=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0] kbits/sec
07-05 04:53:52.260 4285-4285/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone I/huanyutong: Thread processing load: audio=25.112965 video=0.000000  text=0.000000

07-05 04:53:52.450 4285-5556/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone I/huanyutong: Stun packet sent on rtcp for session [0x74e36ba0]

07-05 04:53:52.460 4285-5556/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone I/huanyutong: Sending RTCP SR compound message on session [0x74e36ba0].

07-05 04:53:52.460 4285-4285/com.xuchongyang.easylinphone I/huanyutong: MSAudio_stream_iterate[0x74bf3b20], local statistics available:
                                                                            Local current jitter buffer size: 16777506.0ms
```